# Making a td fill table width

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have a table that has a fixed height of 50px and 100% width.

Inside that table I have two divs, on the same line, like this:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="1"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="2"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

The first div has `float:left`, and the second has `float:right`.

So the table is 100% of the page. I want div2 to wrap it's contents, and div1 to fill the remaining space so that div2 is aligned to the right like this:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| [ DIV 1          (Expands)       ][ DIV 2 AND ITS CONTENTS ] |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

and what I currently get when div1 has less contents than a full line:

```
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| [ DIV 1 ][ DIV 2 ]                                           |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
```

Without a table I can get it to work floating left and right directly, but then when they "get together", they will wrap under each other instead of next to each other.

EDIT: I've added a new jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HRT5E/).
This is the working example.
Try removing all but one links from the left div, and see the result. The second div should stay at the most-right. I hope I explained myself.

Comment: could you please provide some code? and possible a jsfiddle so we can better assist you

Comment: you dont need tables http://jsfiddle.net/WqsTg/

Comment: I was working on the jsfiddle, now it's done, see the edit.

Comment: While HTML5 has deprecated setting widths directly in HTML, in favor of CSS as in your accepted answer, also look at [`<col />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col). Try defining columns with `width="0*"` for minimal width and `width="100%"` for maximum width.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Solved adding the `width:100%` to the table.

http://jsfiddle.net/HRT5E/1/

```
table {
    width:100%;
}
```

Answer (score 44):

Use the "colspan" property of td. Ex:

```
    <td colspan=75%> info </td>
```

Comment: I don't want a fixed width. What I want is that the right div has some width, and the left div adapts it's width to fill the rest of the table, instead of having the right div move.

Comment: This answer is incorrect and not following the HTML standard. [`<td>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/td) `colspan`:
This attribute contains a non-negative integer value that indicates for how many columns the cell extends. Its default value is 1." While HTML5 has deprecated setting widths directly in HTML, look at [`<col />`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/col).

Answer (score 3):

Just add `width: 100%` to first `td` and browser will fill it's width automatically.

Answer (score 0):

First, your table doesn't appear to be set to the full width of the page at all. You want to add a width style or width attribute to the markup.

Next just set a fixed width on the right "div" (or more accurately `<TD>`) and the first one will fill the remaining space.

As others have pointed out, the wrapper table seems unnecessary though.